# Jboss clustered env and communicate via jms (dependencies)

Tags: jboss, dependencies, jms

I'm connecting via jms, and I have had problems with sending jms messages until I add all jars from jboss client folder. It solved the problem but my app weight now +5MB and I'm sure that not all ofthem are required. How can i check which jars are really needed? Please dont tell me I have to remove one by one :)

I also want to ask U about jboss.jar I cant find groupId artifactId for jboss 5.1.0.GA help..

Answer (score 0):

I lifted this from think 1.3 docs I think your up in the 1.4's somwhere

```
*

  jboss-messaging-client.jar - This is available in the messaging distribution
*

  jbossall-client.jar - This is available in your $JBOSS_HOME/client directory
*

  $JBOSS_HOME/server/<SERVER_NAME>/deploy/jboss-aop.deployer/jboss-aop.jar

  JBoss AOP 1.5.5.GA+

  http://repository.jboss.com/jboss/aop/1.5.5.GA/lib/

  (For AOP, sometimes you have to use a specific JAR according to your JVM of choice. Use the most convenient for you)
*

  $JBOSS_HOME/server/<SERVER_NAME>/lib/javassist.jar

  Javassist 3.5.0.GA-brew+

  http://repository.jboss.com/javassist/3.5.0.GA-brew/lib/
*

  $JBOSS_HOME/server/<SERVER_NAME>/lib/trove.jar

  trove 1.0.2-brew
  http://repository.jboss.com/trove/1.0.2-brew/lib/
*

  log4j
```

If you look at the community documentation under "Connecting from a remote client" you should get your answer